# How can I fine-tune cowboy's runtime behavior?

Tags: performance, erlang, elixir, cowboy, phoenix-framework

I'm in the process of choosing a technology for my high-throughput web server. I've created two naive implementations, one in Go and one in Elixir, using Phoenix.

I've deployed these versions on an extra large machine on AWS, and used siege to benchmark their performance.

I've managed to increase Go's performance after setting the `GOMAXPROCS`, but running the Elixir version seems to reach its peak performance long before it fully utilizes the machine's CPU or memory.

I couldn't seem to find any documentation or explanation on how I can fine-tune cowboy's behavior in production settings, so it will properly utilize the machine it runs on, and produce the performance everybody talks about...

I'm pretty sure that there is a simple place (file or environment variable) where I can tweak a value or two to produce much better results.

Can anyone tell me where that place may be?

Comment: Not familiar enough with elixir to provide a real answer, but the creator of Cowboy singled out Phoenix as the likely cause of your performance woes. Most of the parameters you can tweak with Cowboy are supplied when you start the service, not from an application config or the like.

Comment: Can you point me to where he says it?

Comment: No, this was in the #erlang channel on freenode when someone pointed out your question. He does not use stackoverflow.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to stop using phoenix?

Comment: If you want to squeeze out performance, try using just plug: github.com/elixir-lang/plug. Otherwise you are comparing a web server to a web framework, which is not really far.

Comment: My suggestion would more accurately be to stop using Elixir. I'm looking at Phoenix's source to see what exactly it's doing with cowboy, and I don't see much outside of declaring dispatch rules. It also marks Cowboy as an optional dependency, so I can't even be sure it's using it at all without seeing what you're doing with Phoenix.

Comment: Also cowboy will use all of your cores by default so you don't need to worry about it. In case you want to customize the number of acceptors via plug or max connections, you can see some options here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex#L13-L17 Feel free to ping us on #elixir-lang on IRC too.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells why "stop using Elixir" is a suggestion? Just because you are not familiar with what Phoenix is doing, it doesn't mean that nobody is.

Comment: @JoséValim - thanks! I will try your suggestions next week, and I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @JoséValim - Because I don't buy it as being production ready, and issues like this are indicative of that. It's a lot harder to tweak for performance in an immature language, and that's what OP is trying to do. My suggestion to stop using Elixir and my observations about what Phoenix is doing were unrelated. :)

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells Why does the ability to configure one LIBRARY from another LIBRARY give you the impression that the LANGUAGE is immature? Elixir directly compiles to Erlang code. I have never heard of someone having performance issues because of Elixir the language.

Comment: @EricMeadows-Jönsson - Because a library is developed for a language, and an immature language has libraries that have been in production for less time. I've not heard of a performance issue with Elixir the language either, but now you've certainly heard of at least one performance issue with a library for Elixir (related to this question).

Comment: Also, saying Elixir compiles directly to Erlang code is a naive interpretation of the process. Elixir generates Erlang's AST, which is then compiled to BEAM byte code. The BEAM compile doesn't do optimizations, so there could certainly be bugs where Elixir parses and produces less efficient code, or even dangerous code. I've not heard of anything to that effect, but it's a possibility. It's a new language with a new syntax and new features; it's not as simple as you make it out to be.

Comment: From Erlang's AST (emitted by Elixir) to BEAM (bytecode) there are plenty optimizations which are shared by both Elixir and Erlang compilers. In fact, Elixir code even pass through the same linting stages as Erlang code.

Comment: Finally, there has also been plenty of instrumentation to ensure we emit performant code. Elixir is more mature than you make it out to be, given 1.0 is planned for this summer (2014) and the remaining backwards incompatible changes have already been publicly listed.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells The Elixir compiler generates a list of Erlang forms which is fed to compile:forms/2. The only Erlang passes not involved in the compilation of Elixir code are epp and erl_parse, see passes_1/1. It then expands records and other boring things (sys_pre_expand) and compiles to Core Erlang, on which constant folding and various peep-hole optims are done, see compile:standard_passes/0 and core_passes/0. The Core is then compiled to BEAM assembly on which most Erlang-specific optims are done, like selective recv (beam_receive) and binary match contexts (beam_bsm), see asm_passes/0.

Comment: although it is in russian, but you may find this helpful:
http://maxim.livejournal.com/392971.html (author's twi: @5HT)

Comment: @JoséValim - Glad to hear it's that far along, and congrats on seeing it there. I haven't been keeping up with it extensively, and I'm sure a lot of progress has been made since I last checked in on it. Given you and nox's comments, I'm clearly wrong about optimizations moving between AST and BEAM, but I stand by my statement that it's not as simple as what Eric made it out to be.

Comment: @nox - I had read somewhere that here weren't any optimizations made in the BEAM system, but you would certainly know better than I. My point still stands that creating a new language is complicated, even when it shares a VM and bytecode ASM with another language. One of the most dramatic shifts in Elixir from Erlang is the introduction of mutable variables, which I suspect took a lot of effort on the part of JoséValim to make work with the BEAM VM.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells Thanks! Btw, it isn't called "mutable variables", it is just "assignment" (while Erlang is "single assignment"). Informally you may also call it "rebinding". And it is quite straight-forward to implement, transforming code into SSA Form is a known compiler pass: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Answer (score 6):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I've re-implemented my project using [plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug) instead of [phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix).

With the same functionality (parsing post body to JSON, calling DynamoDB, reading from an Amnesia table and formatting a JSON response) I've received a much better performance, with far more resource utilization.

I guess I can still "milk" a few more requests per second (currently I get around 500 requests per second), but it is now on-par with the Go implementation of the same thing...

Comment: Glad to know Uri! Feel free to ping us on the elixir-questions mailing list or #elixir-lang on IRC. If you decide to give Phoenix a try, the developers are hanging in the channel too.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough rep to comment directly, so I'll answer here. I'd love to see the numbers you got with Phoenix. Were you running in prod mode? Perf will be much slower if you were running in dev (the default) since code reloading is enabled and checking on every request. Vanilla Plug is going to be doing less work than Phoenix, but not much less. A standard Phoenix Router/Controller should be more or less inline with the Plug code you end up with.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, and I still suspect there is an easy configuration change that might resolve it for phoenix (hence the question). I _do_ run in `prod` (running in `dev` does not work with `exrm` because of the code reload). If you have any other ideas I'll be happy to try them.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project that you're using for the benchmarks?

Comment: https://github.com/uriagassi/elixir_benchmark - this contains JSON parsing, two exits to dynamo db, and one read from a mnesia tabel. I remind you that a very similar implementation of `plug` yielded better results...

Comment: Thanks Uri. It looks like the provided project is just a Hello World app? I'm not seeing any JSOn parsing, DB, mnesia code as described?

Comment: did you find anything interesting?